# Column validation for a choice column to check for condition on other fields

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-list

I'm a newbee to SP. I have a list that has following columns in my custom list in Sharepoint Online.

```
PrjStatus
Name
Start Date
End Date
SummaryLink
and so on...
```

PrjStatus is a choice column with values (INTAKE, ACTIVE, HOLD, COMPLETE, DUPLICATE)

If the user selects 'COMPLETE' for this field, then when he tries to save, it has to check if the 'End Date' & 'SummaryLink' columns has values. If they have values, then the row gets saved. Otherwise a custom message should come up and it shouldn't let the user save.

I tried various things by setting formulas in column validtion on the PrjStatus column but none of them are working. Pls advice.

I'm using this formula, but it isn't working giving the following error

> =IF([Project Status]="COMPLETE",AND(NOT(ISBLANK([SummaryLink])),NOT(ISBLANK([End
>   Date]))),TRUE)

Error received

```
The formula cannot refer to another column.  Check the formula for spelling mistakes or update the formula to reference only this column
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't create formulas in column validation on the PrjStatus column, because the formula cannot refer to another column.

You can create list validation.

Navigate to list settings->Validation settings->create the following formula->save:

```
=IF(PrjStatus="COMPLETE",AND(NOT(ISBLANK(SummaryLink)),NOT(ISBLANK([End Date]))),TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou Lisa. I'm trying to navigate but I don't see any 'Validation Settings' under List Settings. I'm on SHarepoint online. I clicked on the gear icon at teh top --> List settings, and this is the page I see. THere's no validation settings here (unfortunately I'm not able to paste the image here, but here's the settings I have          -----General Settings
   List name, description and navigation
   Versioning settings
   Advanced settings
   Rating settings
   Audience targeting settings
   Metadata navigation settings
   Per-location view settings
   Form settings